# S:Iterator not showing up all data from action

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, iterator, action

I have a list in action. When I see the values in action, it is showing up all the values but when I'm trying to print the values on JSP, all values are shoeing up but one value doesn't come up.
JSP code for this is:-

```
<s:iterator value="actionForm.listHD" var="varListHD"   status="userlistStatus">
    <tr>
        <td><s:property value="%{#varListHD.group}"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="%{#varListHD.server}"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="%{#varListHD.serverId}"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="%{#varlistHD.smartMonitoring}"/>
        <s:if test="%{#varListHD.smartMonitoring} == 0">
                <s:property value="getText('text.disable')" />
        </s:if> <s:if test="%{#varListHD.smartMonitoring}==1">
                <s:property value="getText('text.enable')" />
        </s:if></td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

In this,

```
<td><s:property value="%{#varListHD.group}"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="%{#varListHD.server}"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="%{#varListHD.serverId}"/></td>
```

are showing data but :-

```
<td><s:property value="%{#varlistHD.smartMonitoring}"/></td>
```

doesn't. I have checked the value in action, its there.
The variable is String and setter getter are public.

Comment: Can you show me your model and controller .

Comment: private List<StorageReadingPeriodInfo> list = new ArrayList<StorageReadingPeriodInfo>();
    private List<StorageHDPrefailureInfo> listHD = new ArrayList<StorageHDPrefailureInfo>();

    private String sortType = "";
    private String order = "";
    private boolean isEditable = false;

Comment: This is how it is there. Basically the pojo contains two types of list. And in the action, System.out.println("printing smartMonitoringValue ::: "+ actionForm.getListHD().get(0).getsmartMonitoring());:- this is printing value on console

Comment: Your `getsmartMonitoring()` should be `getSmartMonitoring()`.

Comment: Edit and Put Your model and the controller in the question.@ShashwatSharma for Better view

Comment: Actually the problem t=is that same code is working in Struts1.x and I'm facing this issue when I'm changing it with "s:".

Comment: Assuming getters/setters follow proper convention, given the code from your comment, the value attributes value should be changed from "actionForm.listHD" to just "listHD". Personal preference but get rid of the var attribute ("varListHD") and then you can write "%{#varListHD.group}" simply as "group" which to my eyes is way clearer.